# java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected. Rejecting invocation, expected 36 argument registers, method signature has 37 or more

Tags: java, kotlin, gson, kotlinx.serialization

when I'm trying to decode a bunch of json data represented as a String it crashes and says:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.example.package.MySampleClass$$serializer: failed to verify: 
com.example.package.MySampleClass com.example.package.MySampleClass 
$$serializer.deserialize(kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder):
[0x1E18] Rejecting invocation, expected 36 argument registers, method signature has 37 or more (declaration of 
'com.example.package.MySampleClass $$serializer' appears in 
/data/data/com.example.package/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes11.dex)
```

**To Reproduce**

```
  val response = httpClient.get<HttpResponse>(ApiEndPoints.languages)
  val result = response.readText()
  val jsElement = Json.parseToJsonElement(result)
  val  arr = (jsElement as JsonObject)["data"] as JsonArray
  arr.forEach {
   //    I tried to use 3 different ways but all of them causes the same error.
         val example1 = Json{ignoreUnknownKeys = true}.decodeFromString<LanguageData>(it.toString()) 
   //    val example2 = Json.decodeFromJsonElement(LanguageData.serializer(),it)
   //    val example3 = Json.decodeFromJsonElement<LanguageData>(it)
  }


@Serializable
data class LanguageData(
  @SerialName("code")
    val code: String,
    @SerialName("flag")
    val flag: String,
    @SerialName("keys")
    val keys: Keys,
    @SerialName("name")
    val name: String
)
@Serializable
data class Keys(
@SerialName("AlertMessages")
    val alertMessages: AlertMessages,
    @SerialName("Alerts")
    val alerts: Alerts,
    @SerialName("SampleKey1")
    val sampleKey1: SampleKey1,
    @SerialName("SampleKey2")
    val sampleKey2: SampleKey2
    ...
    @SerialName("MySampleClass")
    val mySampleClass: MySampleClass
)
```

each of the serializable classes has more than 200 fields.
P.S.
There is no difference If I use `LanguageData` as a returned type instead of `HttpResponse`

**Expected behavior**
Decode jsonString response as LanguageData.
**Environment**

- Kotlin version: 1.4.31
- Kotlin serialization Library version: 1.1.0
- Kotlin platforms: JVM, Native
- Gradle version: 4.2.0-beta06

**UPDATE 1.0**

I have removed all key classes except `MySampleClass` and from that class also removed a bunch of fields (there was ~300, now I have just ~20 field) and now it works.

Seems there is some field quantity limitations but how can I resolve that issue?

**UPDATE 1.1**

Tried with Gson and Moshi but it throws the same error. It seems that its not the `Kotlinx.serialization` library issue

```
Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MySampleClass::class.java)

val adapter: JsonAdapter<MySampleClass> = moshi.adapter(MySampleClass::class.java)
    val result = adapter.fromJson(jsonString)
```

**UPDATE 2.0**

The problem appears in Kotlin data classes, seems that `jvm` class constructor can accept max ~244 fields, now I have changed my data class with "sample" class and it works using `Gson` and also tried with my own parsing using `reflection` and it also worked, but using with `Kotlinx.serialization` still throws the same error.